# How do I connect to a Kerberos-secured Kafka cluster with Spark Structured Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kerberos

I am trying to use the Structured Streaming API to connect to a Kerberos-secured Kafka cluster. Below is my code and the output from Spark. I don't see any exceptions, just WARN messages that the client disconnects. What would be a next step to troubleshoot this?

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.{Logger, Level}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("myapp")
      .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "java.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val lines = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker1:9100,broker2:9100")
      .option("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
      .option("sasl.kerberos.service.name", "mysvcname")
        .option("subscribe", "mytopic")
        .load()

    val query = lines.select("value").writeStream.format("console").start()
    query.awaitTermination()
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/02/11 17:15:06 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/02/11 17:15:10 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-cef02569-ab16-4ca2-a9e8-18bcea992c0d--1359730493-driver-0] Bootstrap broker broker2:9100 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
19/02/11 17:15:11 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-cef02569-ab16-4ca2-a9e8-18bcea992c0d--1359730493-driver-0] Bootstrap broker broker1:9100 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
19/02/11 17:15:11 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-cef02569-ab16-4ca2-a9e8-18bcea992c0d--1359730493-driver-0] Bootstrap broker broker2:9100 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
19/02/11 17:15:11 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-cef02569-ab16-4ca2-a9e8-18bcea992c0d--1359730493-driver-0] Bootstrap broker broker1:9100 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
19/02/11 17:15:11 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-cef02569-ab16-4ca2-a9e8-18bcea992c0d--1359730493-driver-0] Bootstrap broker broker1:9100 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
19/02/11 17:15:11 WARN NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-cef02569-ab16-4ca2-a9e8-18bcea992c0d--1359730493-driver-0] Bootstrap broker broker2:9100 (id: -2 rack: null) disconnected
...
```

Comment: How are you providing `jaas.conf` to the executors?

Comment: Eventually the goal is to supply jaas.conf and the keytab file to executoros via the --files option of spark-submit, but for now I'm just trying to get the code above to work in my IDE. I am stumped by the fact that I don't get any exception to indicate what the problem might be.

Comment: The connection cannot be established. In my experience, this is often because the JAAS is not provided correctly. Thus my question... Running in the IDE is only the driver, not the executor

Answer (score 8):

I figured out my problem. When specifying the security protocol option, the option name must be prefixed with "kafka.". This is confusing because for a regular Kafka consumer the option is simply *security.protocol* but for the purpose of configuring Spark both *bootstrap.servers* and *security.protocol* (and presumably any other options/properties you may need) must be prefixed with *kafka.*. My original code was:

```
.option("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
```

the correct option is:

```
.option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
```

Here's the complete code that works:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.INFO)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.INFO)

    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .appName("myapp")
      .config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "java.security.auth.login.config=c:/krb/jaas.conf")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val lines = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "broker1:9100,broker2:9100")
      .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")
      .option("subscribe", "mytopic")
      .load()

    val query = lines.select("value").writeStream.format("console").start()
    query.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

For reference, here's the content of the jaas.conf file:

```
KafkaClient {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  keyTab="c:/krb/mykeytab.keytab"
  principal="myaccount@mydomain.int"
  storeKey=true
  useTicketCache=false
  serviceName="myservicename";
};
```

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation that explains the "kafka." prefix needs to be added: 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations